# avoid form data getting clear on form submission

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, validation

I am using a html form to get user data using laravel php. On form submit I am executing an api which in Web.php is defined as

```
Route::post('/register_user', 'UserRegistrationController@registerUser');
```

which executes,

```
public function registerUser(Request $request){
    
    $apiResult = $this->executeApi($request->input('mobile_no'));
      
    if($apiResult === "Success"){
   
            return view('further_view');

    }else{

            toastr()->error('Registration Failed. Please check mobile number.');
            return back();
    }

}
```

**html code**

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mobile_no') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                             <label for="mobile_no">Mobile No</label>
                             <input type="text" name="mobile_no" class="form-control" id="mobile_no" value="{{ old('mobile_no') }}" placeholder="Enter Mobile No" required>
                             <small class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('mobile_no') }}</small>
                        </div>
```

My issue here is , whenever my $apiResult === "Success" condition goes false, i get toast message on screen but my page get refreshed and all the data user has typed gets cleared from the input box.
Hence my question is how can I show the toast messages without form being cleared or how would I prevent the input box getting cleared on such conditions.

I am using this Toast library
https://github.com/yoeunes/toastr

Comment: what is `toastr()`?

Comment: hi , added link in question.
https://github.com/yoeunes/toastr

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#old-input Flashing Input Then Redirecting

Comment: @lagbox hi . Flashing input then redirecting perfect solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use a session to store the data. For example:

```
session()->put('forms.mobile_no', $request->get('mobile_no'));
```

Your HTML:

```
<input value="{{ $mobile_no }}" type="text" name="mobile_no" class="form-control" id="mobile_no" placeholder="Enter Mobile No" required>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to return the error message back with this after the toastr call:

```php
return redirect->back()->withInput();
```